# How to get a good lightmap bake in Blender?

Tags: texture-baking

Edit: Thanks to @Leander we figured out that's the right way to do what I'm trying to do is baking 'Combined' and replacing the base color with that. It gives the right results and doesn't seem to take longer to bake. I'll post a better answer once I've wrapped my head around all of it exactly.

I'm looking for some help on baking a lightmap. What am I doing wrong?

This is my scene in cycles:
[image]

This is my baking result with a 2048x2018 texture (notice the harsh shadows on the cube and sphere, and the faceting on the sphere even though it's set to shade smooth):
[image]

My UV layout (all objects are merged into one, for simplicity):
[image]

UV layout (details of the sphere, to show that my faces aren't overlapping and are clearly separated by about 2 pixels):[image]

And finally my settings, sampling is fairly low to reduce baking time, I don't mind having noise for testing purpose, the problem is the harsh shadows and the faceting. Don't suggest subdividing the sphere please, I'm just testing for another project, this scene would work fine in an Unreal 4 light-map bake so it should also work fine in Blender I think. Changing samples won't fix those 2 issues.

[image]

Comment: You are baking the shadows, if you want to bake what you're seeing in your first viewport render image, then bake "Combined".

Comment: I just want the shadows, no AO, no diffuse, nothing but the shadows from my light sources.

Comment: Well what you baked are the "shadows". With a pathtracer with multiple bounces are camera rays "shadows" are hard to define as there are only light rays and no shadow rays. Could you maybe post an example of your successful bake in the game engine which you want to replicate?

Comment: Hmm I'm confused. It's for webgl integration. Basically I have a scene of an apartment with many objects, but they are all unlit. I've baked AO on those objects when making them, but now I'd like to add a directional light, so what should I bake exactly? In the manual they say that Shaodw baked both shadow and lighting: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html

Comment: If it's for webgl, why would you want to bake ao and directional light separately?

Comment: Because users on their browser can move objects in the scene (so we have pre-backed AO on individual objects as part of their individual set of texture), then when everything is placed the idea is to bake the lighting information remotely. Does that make sense? Baking speed is very important, so if I can avoid baking everything it would be great, my idea was just to bake lighting and multiply it on top of my base color just like AO, except for every object in the scene... I guess this isn't a smart solution after all. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106947/discussion-between-leander-and-arthur-blaquart).